# skip_before_action callbacks in Rails 5.1 and inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've just upgraded my app to Rails 5.1 and I've been bitten by the new behaviour of skip_before_action callbacks. i.e. if callback is not defined at the time I try to skip it, it raises an error.

I know that I can pass raise: false like

```
skip_before_action :authorise, raise: false
```

But wondering if there's a better way to do it.

My main problem is that with eager load set to true, the new behaviour messes up with modular setup of my controllers.

Basically I've got dir `app/controllers/api`
with `module_controller.rb`:

```
module Api
  class ModuleController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :authorise
  end
end
```

Then I've got `app_chats_controller.rb` which skips the authorise callback:

```
module Api
  class AppChatsController < ModuleController
    skip_before_action :authorise
  end
end
```

With eager load, `app_chats_controller.rb` gets loaded first, which means callback is not yet defined and without `raise: true` error is raised.

If I have to bite the bullet and add `raise: false` to everything, so be it, but surely there's a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `require 'module_controller'` to the top of `app_chats_controller.rb`

Comment: That kinda works, but shouldn't Rails module resolution figure it out by itself?

Comment: Do you have `Rails.application.config.enable_dependency_loading` set to `true`?

Comment: I'm an idiot. I was inheriting module controller in one place from ActionController::Base, not ApplicationController...